# Django query is not returning all the records

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I am trying to do a simple query but I just don’t understand why I am only getting 1 row when it should be in this example 2:

And I am trying to get all the rows where the externalID = 45454
By doing:

```
context['report'] = Report.objects.filter(externalID =  self.kwargs.get('reportID'))
```

I can see on the debug I get

```
SELECT "data_app_report"."id", "data_app_report"."main_contact_id", "data_app_report"."company_id", "data_app_report"."created", "data_app_report"."externalID", "data_app_report"."success", "data_app_report"."amountrequested" FROM "data_app_report" WHERE "data_app_report"."externalID" = '''45454'''
```

And my table looks like

[image]

I guess I am doing something wrong in the query but I just don’t know what, I thought having filter will allow me to get all of the records

This are the 2 models:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    main_contact = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='companyreport', default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    externalID = models.CharField(default='0000000', max_length=35, unique = False, editable=False) #ONE PERSON CAN HAVE MULTIPLE BANKING IN THE SAME OPP, THEN THE REF IS THE SAME
    success = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    amountrequested = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class ReportURL(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reporturls')
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique = False, default='html')
    report_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
```

This is my view

```
class ExtAccView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'data_app/ext_access.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reportID'] = self.kwargs.get('reportID')
        context['access'] = self.kwargs.get('access')

        #GET THE COMPANY INFORMATION
        try:
            context['company'] = CompanyDetail.objects.get(companyExternalKey =  self.kwargs.get('access'))
        except Exception as e:
            context['message'] = 'The company doesnt match the values you submitted ' + self.kwargs.get('access')
            return context

        #GET THE REPORT AND WE NEED TO DOUBLE CHECK IF THE REPORT COMPANY IS THE SAME AS ABOVE
        try:
            # context['report'] = Report.objects.get(externalID =  self.kwargs.get('reportID'))
            context['report'] = Report.objects.filter(externalID =  self.kwargs.get('reportID'))
        except Exception as e:
            context['message'] = 'No reports found with that reference: ' + self.kwargs.get('reportID')
            return context

        return context
```

This is my template (ext_access.html)

```
{% for r in reportURL %}
    {{ r.report_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your model ?

Comment: How do you *render* the element? What class-based view are you using? Please include an MWE in your question.

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede I have added the model and also the view and the html.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added more details into the question, but basically i access them by {% for r in reportURL %}, regarding MWE, I am sorry i am just learning django I am not really sure what you means by MWE, thanks

Comment: What is `reportURL`? In the context you have only `report`, right? Is it just a typo or there is some logic we cannot see in the description?